# How do I burn the Windows 10 ISO to a USB?

Tags: grub2, usb, windows, live-usb, iso

I did the `dd` method and it wrote the iso to the USB drive, but I'm not sure that's all I have to do because it is Windows and may not have GRUB and I'm not sure so I'm asking the experts.

`winusb` does not work for Windows 10 so this is different from earlier questions.

Comment: Which `dd` method did you use? Also where did you get the ISO?

Comment: @wilf i got it from the official windows 10 site (http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/preview-iso)

Comment: @Wilf i used `sudo dd if=/home/sakurakami/Downloads/Windows.iso of=/dev/sdf bs=4M`

Comment: @Wilf the operation was successful and i even verified the SHA-1 hash with `openssl sha1 Windows.iso`

Comment: @karel no WinUSB didn't work.

Comment: @Wilf I still don't know how. I've gotten a lot of advice but none of it seems to work.

Comment: sry,  quickly read 'the operation was sucessful' - how have you checked that it doesn't work, have you tried a Virtual Machine, or rebooting and booting from the USB. `dd` I though would of worked fine, as it just copies the iso's contents. What format (ext4, fat32, etc) and make is the USB stick?

Comment: @Wilf "quickly read 'the operation was sucessful" what is that? I tried booting from it haha and it didn't work. I thought dd would work two and its whatever format i want but it was ntfs and it's a kingston data traveler 3.0. i've used it as a bootable before plenty of times haha just cant get windows to work haha

Comment: @wilf i tried a virtual machine but it didnt work but it looks like i have advice on that one second haha

Comment: Are you using UEFI or (legacy) BIOS?

Comment: @alb3rtano0012 im on a computer that came with windows 7, so BIOS.

Comment: To be honest WinUSB (1.0.11) somehow worked for me. Needed to wait for some time to let it finish the task though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I create a Windows bootable USB stick using Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/289559/how-can-i-create-a-windows-bootable-usb-stick-using-ubuntu)

Comment: See [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/487970/301745) specifically on the duplicate I just flagged. I've confirmed it works for Windows 10, MBR and GPT modes.

Comment: A quick comment about boot usb - may not be applicable.  On my CPU, when I choose 'restart' and plug in a USB, I often do not see it if the EFI, and I actually have to power off the computer to be able to see and boot from USB.

Answer (score 40):

I tried all the ways in this thread and none worked (and seriously, the question is about specifically writing *to an USB key*, why would people propose copying the ISO to another partition instead ??).

The solution that did the trick for me (assuming your USB drive is `/dev/sdc`):

- Run gparted
- Create a new partition table on `sdc`, type `msdos`
- Create a NTFS partition, set the boot flag on it
- Extract the iso (can be done with `7z x windows10.iso`)
- Copy the content (via `cp`, `rsync`, a GUI, whatever) to the mounted NTFS partition (certainly `/dev/sdc1`)
- The last, **critical** step, taken from this post : https://superuser.com/a/817656/248812 is :

  `sudo ms-sys -7 /dev/sdc`.

  ms-sys is available in a ppa :
  https://launchpad.net/~lenski/+archive/ubuntu/ms-sys

Without `ms-sys`, blinking cursor on boot when the USB key is inserted.

With it, windows logo shows up.

Comment: This worked for me for Windows 10. About ms-sys, I downloaded the deb directly from https://launchpad.net/~lenski/+archive/ubuntu/ms-sys/+files/ms-sys_2.2.0-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb and installed it with `dpkg -i <deb_file>`.

Comment: This worked and it booted, although it throws a blue screen of death...

Comment: For Fedora users, `ms-sys` packages can be found here: https://copr.fedorainfracloud.org/coprs/scorpionit/ms-sys/

Comment: For Arch users, ms-sys is on [the aur](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/ms-sys)

Comment: This works if you have a MBR partition, if you are having a GPT partition scheme, try this instead https://askubuntu.com/a/487970/80788

Comment: "Copy the content" - what content? It's an ISO file?

Comment: @ChrisStryczynski yes, copy what's inside the ISO

Comment: ms-sys gives an apt update error about security, doesnt work. ubuntu 18

Comment: @donbright I installed it from source from GitHub, random web search... I had to move a char[] array in file.c  - it's defined only for FreeBSD otherwise, but then it built.

Comment: I'm using gparted 1.0.0.  I do not see how/where to set boot flag as per this answer.

Comment: The above did not work for me, but this did:  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick/post

Comment: @a coder , open your device in gparted by selecting it in the top-right corner, right-click on of the partitions listed in the center of the screen, select manage flags, check Boot, and then close

Comment: I found it was also necessary to write a separate EBR to the individual partition with ms-sys -n /dev/sdX1.  Once I'd done that the USB just worked.

Answer (score 15):

You don't need a USB, DVD or other external medium to install a Windows 10 Install Disk (ISO) starting from a Ubuntu only installation. It is possible to extract the image or ISO file to a partition of one your hard disks, preferable not the one your will use for a new Windows installation, and use it.

For the following steps, a working GRUB configuration should be present:

1. Make sure you have a bootable and formatted NTFS partition present. Below, the partition will identified by `(hd0,5)` where `hd0` is the containing hard disk with MSDOS or MBR partition table layout.
2. Mounting the image will make it easier to extract it's contents. If Disk Image Mounter refuses to mount the iso file you can always use this command to mount any iso file:

   ```
   sudo mount -o loop [Image_Path] [Mount_Point]
   ```
3. Copy the contents of new loop device to the NTFS partition.
4. Now add a GRUB entry for Windows 10. This will make it possible for the bootloader GRUB to find install disk contained in the partition. Open `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` in text editor as root and add these lines

   ```
   menuentry 'Windows 10 Install Disk' {
   set root=(hd0,5)
   insmod part_msdos
   insmod ntfs
   insmod ntldr
   drivemap -s (hd0) ${root}
   ntldr /bootmgr
   }
   ```

   change the root if needed, accordingly.
5. Save and restart computer. Boot into the right item of your updated GRUB menu.

Watch this Youtube tutorial https://youtu.be/1Y4JXv9r5Ug

Comment: It will not work if you're installing to the same partition or drive that you're booting from.

Comment: @ThisNameBetterBeAvailable How is this the correct answer?  It doesn't even put the data on USB.

Comment: @jbo5112 The answer mentions that extracting to a USB is unneccessary, and that extracting directly to a partition on the hard drive works too, as long as the correct code is added to grub.cfg

Comment: @ThisNameBetterBeAvailable How is extracting to a USB unnecessary to "burn the Windows 10 ISO to a USB," as the original asker was requesting.  They might be wanting to use this on multiple computers.

Comment: @jbo5112 That wasn't mentioned in the question, so assuming his goals and trying to help him with that is what happened.

Comment: @ThisNameBetterBeAvailable It's in the title of the question.

Comment: @Sumna: I followed the instructions, all fine until , on the "step 1 - Select the driver to install" of the installation, an error message pops up: "A media driver your computer needs is missing". Apparently, it refuses to use the data from the hard disk, wants a USB or DVD.

Comment: that's a solution I didn't think about and actually shortcuts the way to a windows installation and hence that's what we actually want, it's a viable  answer. I also can reuse this last partition of the drive everytime I need

Answer (score 7):

You can copy all the ISO contents to the flash drive and make it bootable.

So, first of all, install GParted from software center or from terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install gparted
```

Then, open it from dash or terminal:

```
gksudo gparted
```

After that, choose the flash drive from the menu in top right corner.
There should be one partition. If you haven't any data to backup, reformat it as `ntfs` (`bootmgr` doesn't work right on fat32), click `Apply` (the tick in the header menu). Right-click the partition, choose `Manage flags` and check `boot`.

Then, you can mount it through your file manager (`nautilus` is default for GNOME and Unity).

Mount the ISO file:

```
sudo mount -o loop [path to iso] [mountpoint]
```

Then, you can copy all contents from the ISO mountpoint to the flash drive via the file manager.

Reboot your computer and set the USB Flash Drive to boot first.

Comment: Yeah I tried booting it but it appears to have not worked. Can you give me the list of commands you used?

Comment: I have just copied from the file manager and enabled the boot flag from GParted.

Comment: @SakuraKaminari - could you add more details as to how it has appeared not to work?

Comment: @wilf it didn't boot.

Comment: @alb3rtano0012 how can i mount it? It doesn't want to mount. it's currently on /dev/sdf

Comment: I'll edit my answer.

Comment: This solution doesn't work. My computer booted with a blinking cursor... I down voted but my rep is too low for it to matter.

Comment: Perhaps this also needs adding a new MBR? I can imagine that some USB sticks have it and some don't (editing the partition table does not clear the MBR). To add the MBR, run `sudo dd if=/usr/lib/syslinux/mbr/mbr.bin of=/dev/sdc` (replacing `sdc` with your usb stick cdevice) as suggested by Kjeld's answer below.

Answer (score 4):

I managed to do this with WoeUSB. To install the WoeUSB command line tool snap package in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu open the terminal and type:

```
sudo snap install --edge woe-usb  
sudo snap connect woe-usb:removable-media
```

To launch the woe-usb snap package command line tool run the following command:

```
/snap/bin/woe-usb.woeusb
```

If you get a `permission denied` error click the *Permissions* button on the *woe-usb* screen in Ubuntu Software and toggle the permissions options from OFF to ON as shown in the below screenshot.

[image: woe-usb Permissions]

Comment: worked perfectly, thank you! :)

Comment: This was the easiest solution for me. For Windows 10, you'll have to select NTFS as the file system.

Answer (score 2):

The ms-dos package is quite old an unmaintained. It does not load on ubuntu 16-04. Instead use the syslinux package which most likely already is installed:
http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2013/08/repair-windows-mbr-from-ubuntu/

Also cp to an ntfs partition is slow. Extract the iso directly to sdc1

- Run gparted
- Create a new partition table on sdc, type msdos
- Create a NTFS partition, set the boot flag on it
- Copy the iso

  sudo dd of=/dev/sdc1 if=Win10_1703_English_x64.iso bs=4M
- Create MBR

  sudo dd if=/usr/lib/syslinux/mbr/mbr.bin of=/dev/sdc

Comment: worked perfectly, should be the accepted answer. Thanks.

Comment: I just tried this (using `Win10_1709_Dutch_x64.iso` [downloaded from MS](https://www.microsoft.com/software-download/windows10)) and it did not work for me. Booting the resulting USB stick failed with `Missing operating system` (which I think is printed by the MBR), booting on an actual system shows a similar message from the BIOS (which probably hides the MBR message). I wonder how this is supposed to work? A .iso does not contain NTFS?

Comment: Should be an accepted answer - it is the easiest and does not require any external dependencies. dd'ing the .iso did not work for me though - it still created ufs filesystem instead of existing NTFS, but simple cp followed by dd'ing MBR worked like a charm

Answer (score 1):

If you weren't sure, then how can you say that the `dd` method worked? Also, that ain't the way. You have to use Rufus to make the USB drive bootable;not that I discourage the dd practices, since it is Windows we are talking about, I believe it is best to use Rufus to handle this for you.

If you have a Windows installation already, then boot into it and follow the steps below or else, use virtualbox.

**PROCEDURE:**

According to: http://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-to-install-windows-10-technical-preview-from-a-flash-drive/

you'll need at least 4GB flash drive (8GB for 64-bit).

--> Download and run Rufus, then insert your flash drive, making sure it doesn't contain any important data. (It's about to get wiped.) Rufus should automatically detect the drive and list it in the Device field. (If not, select the drive manually.)

--> Notice the check box marked, "Create a bootable disk using." Click the drive icon at the far right, then navigate to wherever you saved the Windows 10 ISO file. Select it, and then click Start. (All the other default settings in Rufus should be fine.)

--> This will take some time, perhaps as long as 20-30 minutes. Don't be alarmed (or confused) if an Explorer window appears for the flash drive; just leave it alone until Rufus reports "DONE." Then you can close the program and drive window and remove the drive.

--> Now it's time for the old PC. Plug the flash drive into a USB port, then power up the system. Most likely, it won't be configured to boot from an external drive by default, so you may need to jump into a startup menu or the BIOS during the POST. Ultimately, you need to force the machine to boot from the flash drive. Once you've done that, reboot, then follow the Windows installation instructions.

All the best!

Comment: but I don't have windows. the reason i want windows 10 is because my windows 7 doesn't work so I can't burn with rufus. is what i did ok?

Comment: Then, install Windows in VirtualBox. Or, download WinUSB as suggested in: http://askubuntu.com/questions/289559/how-can-i-create-a-windows-bootable-usb-stick-with-ubuntu

The link shows how to regarding Windows 8 but I bet it would work with Windows 10.

Comment: well it seems that winusb didnt work reliably and idk ill try it but

Comment: Well, then it is best to use VirtualBox now. If you are trying to use Windows, then it is best to host Windows (virtually for the time being).

Comment: I got this from WinUSB: 
Installation failed !
Exit code: 256
Log:
Formating device...
Error: /dev/sdf: unrecognised disk label

Comment: i have no idea how to run windows virtually :/

Comment: It is very simple. Open the terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T) and type: sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install virtualbox-qt -y.

After the installation is successful, type 'virtualbox' WITHOUT sudo.

Now, create a virtual machine in the virtualbox and place a Windows installation disc into the DVD Drive of the laptop (OR) the windows 10 preview iso would suffice.

Now follow the on-screen instructions and create the virtual machine. On first time run, it will prompt the CD/DVD source. IF you had the disc in DVD drive, choose it or browse for the Windows 10 ISO file.

Comment: I got from VM on first boot:
Failed to open a session for the virtual machine Windows 10.
AMD-V is disabled in the BIOS (or by the host OS). (VERR_SVM_DISABLED).

Comment: It says the error right. Reboot the PC, enter the BIOS setup and look for anything which starts with "Advanced" except in Power management or with anything of such context.

"Virtualisation" should be the word you would be looking for and any option you find relating to that would suffice!
Just be careful not to tamper any OTHER settings.

Comment: I'll try that if nothing else works but i'd rather not mess with bios

Comment: @Surya:You cannot install Windows that way. Windows pairs with hardware as soon as you install it. No-DRM OSes work just fine. I have transerred Ubuntu installation twice from a virtual machine.

Comment: @erkin you don't understand, I asked the OP to install Windows( if he doesn't have it) so that he could run rufus.

Comment: I understand from my own experience that Rufus is the best tool on windows. But this is not the best answer as it’s best to solely use Ubuntu to get the work done. Ubuntu may be running on old hardware, which makes the use of VirtualBox totally irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

Found a much easier solution. Mount the ISO with loop etc and -t udf. Copy everything in a spare NTFS partition. Mark this partition as **boot** in gparted. Run `sudo update-grub` and reboot.

Comment: Note that you will be able to boot this usb drive only from the computer you were running the "update-grub"

Comment: @ozma This answer doesn't concern a USB drive.

Comment: @forresthopkinsa You are right, my comment was meant to prevent such an error

Comment: This method worked until the Windows 10 Installer complained about booting from a ntfs partition and aborted.

Answer (score 1):

I tried with the `ms-sys`, it ran but I could not get the USB to boot. However, this worked:

```
sudo apt install woes
sudo woeusb --target-filesystem NTFS --device Win10.iso /dev/sdX
```

where the `/dev/sdX` must be your USB key.