# How can I create a Windows 10 boot usb from ubuntu?

Tags: partitioning, windows, live-usb, 15.10, windows-10

I used `sudo dd bs=4M if=Windows.iso of=/dev/sdc1` and set the boot flag in gparted but no install disk just the just the normal usb in the uefi and trying to boot off the normal USB did nothing.

Extra info I am on Ubuntu 15.10 and I had the usb using gpt and fat32.

Comment: Take a look at this two Discussions :
[How can I create a Windows bootable USB stick with Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/289559/how-can-i-create-a-windows-bootable-usb-stick-with-ubuntu) And 
[How do I burn the Windows 10 ISO to a USB?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/599746/how-do-i-burn-the-windows-10-iso-to-a-usb)

Comment: Sorry, for this I recommend **Rufus** windows-only utility (https://rufus.akeo.ie/). *You need a GPT partition and the .ISO content copied onto it, but Rufus just works ..*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One tool that you can use is Unetbootin, which I have found to be quite reliable when creating bootable USB sticks.

You can install Unetbootin with `sudo apt-get install unetbootin`, and use it via `sudo unetbootin`.

**NOTE:** Unetbootin is a graphical applications, it just requires root-level privileges to be able to modify the USB and make it bootable, hence the launch via Terminal and not the Dash.

Comment: Unetbootin did not find the USB drive.

Comment: @user5448026 Search in the Dash for 'Disks', and reformat the USB drive, that may fix it

Comment: If Unetbootin still doesn't find it, be sure to format it as FAT32.