# How do i factory reset my pc back to Factory settings on ubuntu 16.04 .1 LTS

Tags: reset

I tried dual boot with  Ubuntu and it deleted my window and i'm stuck with Ubuntu, i prefer windows over this and would like to factory reset my pc. If anyone know how and could help me please do!

Comment: You have to check with your Manufacturer's manual to see how to recover windows off the hidden partition. But this question is off-topic here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it depends on Manufacturer's options for system recovery.

Comment: When you selected to install Ubuntu you were given two choices 1. Erase windows or 2. Install alongside Windows (dual boot). For option 2. your Windows is still there you just can't see it for whatever reason and recovering via your hidden system partition will erase all your windows data.

Answer (score 1):

If you didn't choose to install Ubuntu alongside Windows, then you're only option is to get a Windows media (a DVD or USB) and reinstall. There's no option for "factory reset" back to Windows once the Windows partition was completely removed.

If you go to the "[Windows 10 ISO](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO/)" download page **from your Ubuntu computer** (either Firefox or Chrome will do - and likely many other browsers, but it must be from Ubuntu, or else Microsoft will just redirect to to the EXE file), you'd be able to select and download an ISO image for Windows 10, after which you can use the [Ubuntu DVD Creator](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/burn-a-dvd-on-ubuntu) to burn the ISO image to a blank DVD, assuming you have a DVD drive available.

If you don't have a DVD drive or blank discs to use, then you can write the downloaded ISO image to a USB drive - though that process is more complicated and requires to use a terminal to run some of the steps. Follow the process detailed in [this Ask Ubuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/840797/6537) (please note that it is not the top voted answer - though you may need to read the top voted answer as well to help you copy the contents of the ISO image to the USB drive, as required).

Comment: I've downvoted your answer because the part where you state you can't download a Windows ISO without an MSDN subscription is incorrect. See this answer on Super User: http://superuser.com/a/1046062/576098 If you revise your answer, I will reverse the downvote.

Comment: @AndroidDev - sorry, my claim was incorrect, and that is regardless of the hack you linked to (which has problems, as I've noted on that page). I'll update. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: I've reversed the vote.

Answer (score 0):

Don't panic. I always suggest to keep a Windows live USB as it saves the trouble when you mess up your system.

What you need here is a Windows live USB or DVD.

If you have access to another computer (yours or friends or family) you can download one. Boot from it and delete the partition where Linux is installed and install Windows on it, fresh.