# how to make bootable USB in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: boot, dual-boot, usb, usb-drive

i'm using Ubuntu 20.04 and i want to make a bootable usb for Wndows 10. woeusb is not working while trying restore disk in diskpart usb is not picking boot can you suggest me better way?

Comment: You can try with [mkusb-plug according to this link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/plug).

Comment: the device is unmounted and you can unplug it. the system might not see the current portable table of the target device unless you re-plug it.   this error is occuring

Comment: It may occur, when the USB drive is slow and writing via the buffers gets choked. 1. Did you unplug and plug it back, and press Enter to continue; 2. It may help, if you overwrite the target drive with zeros. If you installed mkusb via the PPA, you can use mkusb version 12 (alias mkusb-dus) to do that in a safe way. Try with mkusb-plug again after that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use dd command

> sudo dd status=progress if=name-of.iso of=/dev/sdb

if == input file
of == output file

Comment: I don't think cloning with `dd` works to make a boot drive from a Windows 10 iso file. Have you tried?

Comment: This post details methods that have worked for some (https://askubuntu.com/questions/599746/how-do-i-burn-the-windows-10-iso-to-a-usb)

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the ways I found on the internet - **dd**, installing from an repo or from .deb **woeusb**, the creation partitions by **gparted** with **ntfs** and copying the content of the windows-iso with **ms-sys** mbr etc. All these ways are not working for me.
The only way that helped me was:

1. Re-creation of a new **fat32**-partition (not ntfs!) on a flash drive with `gparted`.
2. Installing **unetbootin**:

   `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gezakovacs/ppa`

   `sudo apt-get update`

   `sudo apt-get install unetbootin`
3. Creation the bootable flash drive from windows-iso with **unetbootin**
4. Setting **boot-flag** on the flash-partition by gparted